# ¿Cómo es posible cortar una cadena y ponerla al final en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Los archivos que tengo son mas de mil, por ejemplo voy a mostrar un ejemplo con archivos del dia *2015133 y 2015134*:

```
2015133_0b088_PEO.txt 
2015133_0b088_PED.txt
2015133_0b088_PEN.txt
2015133_0b088_PNO.txt
2015133_0b088_PND.txt
2015133_0b088_PNN.txt

2015134_0b088_PEO.txt 
2015134_0b088_PED.txt 
2015134_0b088_PEN.txt
2015134_0b088_PNO.txt 
2015134_0b088_PND.txt 
2015134_0b088_PNN.txt
```

Y tengo el siguiente código que es para cambiar el nombre de ellos:

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Transforma\\PENS\\') #ubicacion de los archivos a renombrar
        for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace(
            '_0b088_PEO', 'LS.XN.PEO.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PED', 'LS.XN.PED.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PEN', 'LS.XN.PEN.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PNO', 'LS.XN.PNO.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PND', 'LS.XN.PND.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PNN', 'LS.XN.PNN.D' 
        )
    print(newname)

    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

La salida de los archivos es la siguiente ya una vez ejecutado el código:

```
2015133LS.XN.PEO.D.txt
2015133LS.XN.PED.D.txt
2015133LS.XN.PEN.D.txt
2015133LS.XN.PNO.D.txt
2015133LS.XN.PND.D.txt
2015133LS.XN.PNN.D.txt

2015134LS.XN.PEO.D.txt
2015134LS.XN.PED.D.txt
2015134LS.XN.PEN.D.txt
2015134LS.XN.PNO.D.txt
2015134LS.XN.PND.D.txt
2015134LS.XN.PNN.D.txt
```

Como le puedo hacer para que ***los primero 7 números*** los ponga hasta el final, por ejemplo que queden así:

```
LS.XN.PEO.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PED.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PEN.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PNO.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PND.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PNN.D.2015.133

LS.XN.PEO.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PED.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PEN.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PNO.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PND.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PNN.D.2015.134
```

Comment: he modificado la respuesta tomando en cuenta los paths reales, además agregué como obtener el formato exacto que necesitas (incluye "." en la fecha).

Answer (score 2):

Con la idea de @JMEspiz se me ocurre esta:

```
paths = ["2015133_0b088_PEO.txt",
"2015133_0b088_PED.txt",
"2015133_0b088_PEN.txt",
"2015133_0b088_PNO.txt",
"2015133_0b088_PND.txt",
"2015133_0b088_PNN.txt",
"2015134_0b088_PEO.txt",
"2015134_0b088_PED.txt",
"2015134_0b088_PEN.txt",
"2015134_0b088_PNO.txt",
"2015134_0b088_PND.txt",
"2015134_0b088_PNN.txt"]

for path in paths:
    print ("LS.XN."+ path[14:17] + ".D."+ path[:7])
```

Comment: por que a la hora de poner en practica tu idea, corro el script y no tiene problemas pero a la hora de revisar la carpeta no hizo el cambio de nombre

Answer (score 0):

Una solución puede ser simplemente:

Considerando que en `paths` se genera un arreglo similar a:

```
paths = ["C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015133_0b088_PEO.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015133_0b088_PED.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015133_0b088_PEN.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015133_0b088_PNO.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015133_0b088_PND.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015133_0b088_PNN.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015134_0b088_PEO.txt", 
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015134_0b088_PED.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015134_0b088_PEN.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015134_0b088_PNO.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015134_0b088_PND.txt",
"C:\\data\\Transforma\PENS\\2015134_0b088_PNN.txt"]
```

Se puede obtener el formato que deseas mediante:

```
for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace(
            '_0b088_PEO', 'LS.XN.PEO.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PED', 'LS.XN.PED.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PEN', 'LS.XN.PEN.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PNO', 'LS.XN.PNO.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PND', 'LS.XN.PND.D' 
        ).replace(
            '_0b088_PNN', 'LS.XN.PNN.D' 
        ).replace('txt','')    
    a = newname[-12:]
    b = newname[24:31]
    print(a +  b[:4] + '.' + b[4:])
```

Tendrás como salida el formato exacto que deseas:

```
LS.XN.PEO.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PED.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PEN.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PNO.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PND.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PNN.D.2015.133
LS.XN.PEO.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PED.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PEN.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PNO.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PND.D.2015.134
LS.XN.PNN.D.2015.134
```

**[Aquí](https://ideone.com/9qNoRh)** una simulación en línea.

Comment: le agregue la linea que comentas pero a la hora de correr el programa me marca lo siguiente: `print(newname[-12:] + newname[:7])
                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: En python, uno de los detalles importantes a cuidar mientras codificamos es la indentación, asegurate que tienes bien indentado tu código.

Comment: @Houdini puedes usar http://www.cleancss.com/python-beautify/ para formatear tu código.

Comment: hola, a la hora de correr el script como me explicaste no funciono como yo no puse el nombre de cada archivo en `paths` si no lo tengo en un ciclo. y lo corre sin problemas pero no hace el cambio de recorrer la fecha al final, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: OK, he cambiado mi respuesta, era una suposición en base a tu arreglo, pero lo modifiqué como sería realmente ya que lo que se guarda es el path completo dentro de "paths".

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución simple seria usar la función .split que recibe como parámetro un carácter y así dividir el String en una lista.

EDIT: edito para cambiar el ciclo y que renombre los archivos:

```
for path in paths:
    #Primero, separo en partes para trabajar el segmento que voy a renombrar 
    a = path.split("\\")
    # asigno el viejo nombre a manipular
    oldname = a[4]
    #el nuevo nombre basado en el viejo con los detalles que pides.
    newname = "LS.XN."+ oldname[14:17] + ".D."+ oldname[:4] + "." + oldname[4:7] + ".txt"
    #renombro el viejo nombre por el nuevo
    rename_file = os.rename(oldname, newname)
    #Uno de nuevo las rutas
    new_path = os.path.join(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], rename_file)
    print "Nuevo nombre: " + new_path

print "Tarea de renombrado finalizada"
```

y el resultado seria el deseado:

```
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PEO.D.2015.133.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PED.D.2015.133.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PEN.D.2015.133.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PNO.D.2015.133.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PND.D.2015.133.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PNN.D.2015.133.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PEO.D.2015.134.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PED.D.2015.134.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PEN.D.2015.134.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PNO.D.2015.134.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PND.D.2015.134.txt
C:/data/Transforma/PENS/LS.XN.PNN.D.2015.134.txt
Tarea de renombrado finalizada
```

Nota: en mi caso las uri estan divididas por "/" debido a que uso linux, pero en windows deberia ser "\".

Prueba y me comentas.
Saludos

Comment: si logro correr el script, y me imprime esto `LS.XN.PEO.D.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015125
LS.XN.PED.D.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015125
LS.XN.PEN.D.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015125

LS.XN.PEO.D.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015126
LS.XN.PED.D.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015126
LS.XN.PEN.D.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015126

LS.XN.PEO.D.2015.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015127
LS.XN.PED.D.2015.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015127
LS.XN.PEN.D.2015.C:\data\Transforma\PENS\2015127` pero no me cambia el nombre de los archivos

Comment: He editado el codigo para que funcione como esperas, has la prueba y me comentas.

Answer (score 0):

Doy una solución alternativa (quizás haya alguna errata, porque no la he probado):

```
import os

base, _, files = next(os.walk("/lo/que/sea"))
rebautizar = lambda nombre: "LS.XN.{sufijo}.D.{anno}.{dia}".format(
    sufijo=nombre[14:17],
    anno=nombre[:4],
    dia=nombre[4:7]
)

for oldname in files:
    os.rename(
        os.path.join(base, oldname),
        os.path.join(base, rebautizar(oldname))
    )
```